# SQL Server - script to update database columns from varchar to nvarchar if not already nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, alter-table

I am in a situation where I must update an existing database structure from varchar to nvarchar using a script.  Since this script is run everytime a configuration application is run, I would rather determine if a column has already been changed to nvarchar and not perform an alter on the table.  The databases which I must support are SQL Server 2000, 2005 and 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should get you what you need:

```
IF EXISTS 
  (SELECT *
   FROM sysobjects syo
   JOIN syscolumns syc ON
     syc.id = syo.id
   JOIN systypes syt ON
     syt.xtype = syc.xtype
   WHERE 
     syt.name = 'nvarchar' AND
     syo.name = 'MY TABLE NAME' AND
     syc.name = 'MY COLUMN NAME')
BEGIN
   ALTER ...
END
```

Answer (score 26):

You can run the following script which will give you a set of ALTER commands:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + isnull(schema_name(syo.id), 'dbo') + '.' +  syo.name 
    + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + syc.name + ' NVARCHAR(' + case syc.length when -1 then 'MAX' 
        ELSE convert(nvarchar(10),syc.length) end + ');'
   FROM sysobjects syo
   JOIN syscolumns syc ON
     syc.id = syo.id
   JOIN systypes syt ON
     syt.xtype = syc.xtype
   WHERE 
     syt.name = 'varchar' 
    and syo.xtype='U'
```

There are, however, a couple of quick *caveats* for you.

1. This will only do tables. You'll want to scan all of your sprocs and functions to make sure they are changed to `NVARCHAR` as well.
2. If you have a `VARCHAR` > 4000 you will need to modify it to be `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

But those should be easily doable with this template.

If you want this to run automagically you can set it in a `WHILE` clause.

Comment: Be careful with this because you will get all the default values for a new column.  E.g., a non-null varchar will be created as a nullable nvarchar.

Answer (score 4):

The issue with Josef's answer is that it would change `NOT NULL` fields to `NULL` after executing the queries. The following manipulation fixes it:

```
SELECT cmd = 'alter table [' + c.table_schema + '].[' + c.table_name 
 + '] alter column [' + c.column_name + '] nvarchar('
 +CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH<=4000
       THEN CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as varchar(10)) ELSE 'max' END+')' 
 + CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE='NO' THEN ' NOT NULL' ELSE '' END,*
FROM information_schema.columns c
WHERE c.data_type='varchar' 
ORDER BY CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH desc
```

> **Credits to [Igor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31691558/1221203)**

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the space issue and added schema

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + isnull(schema_name(syo.object_id), sysc.name) + '].[' +  syo.name 
    + '] ALTER COLUMN ' + syc.name + ' NVARCHAR(' + case syc.max_length when -1 then 'MAX' 
        ELSE convert(nvarchar(10),syc.max_length) end + ');'
   FROM sys.objects syo
   JOIN sys.columns syc ON
     syc.object_id= syo.object_id
   JOIN sys.types syt ON
     syt.system_type_id = syc.system_type_id
    JOIN sys.schemas sysc ON
    syo.schema_id=sysc.schema_id
   WHERE 
     syt.name = 'varchar' 
    and syo.type='U'
```

Answer (score 0):

Further updated to fix MAX being replaced with -1.

```
SELECT cmd = 'ALTER TABLE [' + c.table_schema + '].[' + c.table_name 
 + '] ALTER COLUMN [' + c.column_name + '] NVARCHAR('
 +CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH<=4000 THEN 
 CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN
 'MAX' ELSE CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(10)) END ELSE 'MAX' END+')' 
 + CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE='NO' THEN ' NOT NULL' ELSE '' END,*
FROM information_schema.columns c
WHERE c.data_type='VARCHAR' 
ORDER BY CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH DESC
```

Credit to [Nezam's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31827056/1781344)

And another one to manage default values:

```
SELECT cmd = 
CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN
    'ALTER TABLE ' + c.table_name + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + d.name + '; ' +
    'ALTER TABLE [' + c.table_schema + '].[' + c.table_name + '] ALTER COLUMN [' + c.column_name + '] ' + 
    'NVARCHAR(' +
    CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH <= 4000 THEN 
        CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN
            'MAX' 
        ELSE 
            CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(10)) 
        END 
     ELSE 
        'MAX' 
    END 
    + ')' +
    CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE='NO' THEN ' NOT NULL' ELSE '' END + '; ' + 
    'ALTER TABLE '+ c.table_name + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + d.name +' DEFAULT '+ c.column_default + ' FOR ' + c.column_name + ';'
ELSE
    'ALTER TABLE [' + c.table_schema + '].[' + c.table_name + '] ALTER COLUMN [' + c.column_name + '] ' +
    'NVARCHAR(' +
    CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH<=4000 THEN
        CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1 THEN
            'MAX' 
        ELSE 
            CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(10)) 
        END 
    ELSE 
        'MAX' 
    END
    + ')' +
    CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE='NO' THEN ' NOT NULL' ELSE '' END 
END,d.name, c.*
FROM information_schema.columns c
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.default_constraints d ON d.parent_object_id = object_id(c.table_name)
AND d.parent_column_id = columnproperty(object_id(c.table_name), c.column_name, 'ColumnId')
WHERE c.data_type='VARCHAR' 
ORDER BY CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH DESC
```