# MS-SQL: Convert all instances of one column type to another?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have an SQL Server 2008 database, which contains about 40 tables.  Most of them contain at least a couple of `varchar` columns, and I want to convert every single one of those to `nvarchar` (of the same length).  Also want to convert a number of `text` fields to `nvarchar(MAX)`.  Is there a simple, straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems very similar to the following question:

[SQL Server Script to Update Database Columns from varchar to nvarchar...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179987/sql-server-script-to-update-database-columns-from-varchar-to-nvarchar-if-not-al)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep, that does it -- didn't find that in my initial search.  Thanks!