# How to alter db object datatype from varchar to nvarchar without defaulting to null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have tables,stored procedures and functions using `varchar` but to support arabic text i would need to change them to `nvarchar`. I have this script for tables

```
select cmd = 'alter table [' + c.table_schema + '].[' + c.table_name + '] alter column [' + c.column_name + '] nvarchar',* from information_schema.columns c where c.data_type='varchar' order by CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH desc
```

Using this i get a query which i can copy paste and execute to change varchar to nvarchar but they default the non nullable columns to include null which is a **big** issue. I need to retain the nullable as nullable and non nullable as non nullable.

Next, issue is that i would have to manually edit the stored procedures and functions to implement this change wherever needed. Is there some workaround script for atleast altering the parameters safely ?

Note that do not have views in the database and some `varchar` declarations have size to 8000 too.

Please give me a safe solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add

```
+ CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE='NO' THEN ' NOT NULL' ELSE '' END
```

Also, you need to add `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` to `nvarchar`.

As for parameters in stored procedures, I'd better did it manually.

**EDITED** 
Full query

```
SELECT cmd = 'alter table [' + c.table_schema + '].[' + c.table_name 
 + '] alter column [' + c.column_name + '] nvarchar('
 +CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH<=4000
       THEN CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as varchar(10)) ELSE 'max' END+')' 
 + CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE='NO' THEN ' NOT NULL' ELSE '' END,*
FROM information_schema.columns c
WHERE c.data_type='varchar' 
ORDER BY CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH desc
```

Comment: can you please modify the full query and post it in your answer to be crystal clear. Thanks

Comment: and i need to change the non nullable `varchar` to non nullable `nvarchar` too. Will this query work ?

Comment: @Nezam I edited the answer. " i need to change the non nullable `varchar` to non nullable `nvarchar`". Yes, if you mean `NOT NULL`

Comment: Thanks a lot! and the size of 8000 will not be an issue of nvarchar ?

Comment: @Nezam Yes, it will be. `Nvarchar` cannot be longer than 4000, for this cases you need to use `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: so suppose if this generated query has somewhere `nvarchar(8000)` , what will be the possible outcome of this execution ?

Comment: @Nezam You'll get the error. I edited the full script for this scenario: CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH greater than 4000 will be replaced with MAX.

Comment: one of the queries which this query returned was `alter table [dbo].[Merchant] alter column [Address] nvarchar(-1)` because the column was `varchar(MAX)` already.